# Is It Possible To Write PHP Data To Python Script Using Python's stdin?

Tags: python, php, apache

I have some data generated by a php script that I need to send to a Python script to do some additional processing. Writing the data to a file and then reading it from the Python script is unfortunately not an option for this case. Is there a way for me to maybe get a handle for the standard in of the Python script so I can just write to that? Reading from stdin in Python is simple enough.

I don't know if this is even possible and I'm open to any other suggestions! Also happy to provide any pertinent details I may have missed in this question.

Using PHP 7.4.3 and Python 3.6 on Apache web server.

Comment: Of course; you could run something like `php source.php | python middleware.py | php resurrection.php`. But perhaps more versatile is the fact that there are a million formats that both these languages support (plain text, json, xml, various database systems even, and on and on ...). The best choice really depends on the specifics and perhaps on which things you have experience with

Comment: Does this need to be done in a web context, or could it be done on the CLI exclusively? The latter is easier. Otherwise, you can use [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to read/write to streams

Comment: The pipeline example was a cli suggestion yes. To be fair, there are literally thousands of ways to do this, its really about the specifics of what kind of data you want to share, how much control you have over each software stack or the servers it runs on ...etc

Comment: @ChrisHaas great question, yes this needs to be done in a web context. The php script is triggered by a webhook. I'm essentially passing the headers and payload of the webhook to the Python script. It comes in as a json object.

Comment: @Raxi i do indeed have full control over the server